# Did ARel change the escaping behaviour of matches at some point?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

I have a scope implemented like this:

```
  scope :filtered_by_name_contains,     ->(param) { where(arel_table[:name].matches("%#{param}%")) }
```

Now, if param contains a backslash... let's say `param == "a\\b"`...

With our code on Rails 3, this was working, and returning the expected results.

On Rails 5, this no longer works, and *doesn't* return the expected results. However, the user reporting this issue noticed that if they enter double backslashes, it somehow matches.

What changed? I don't remember seeing anything like this mentioned in the upgrade docs.